# Using Excel VBA custom class to wrap database calls and return recordsets

Tags: syntax, excel, ado, vba

I have the following code. The intent is to have this utility class that I use to hold all my database work and just return populated ADODB.RecordSet objects. I am getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Property Get RecordSetCustomers() As ADODB.Recordset
    m_myDB.BuildConfig
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM vw_customers"

    cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
    cmd.ActiveConnection = m_myDB.DbConnection
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    RecordSetCustomers = rs
End Property
```

The m_myDB is an object/class that holds all my database configuration/connection params.

The error I am receiving is: 'Compile Error: Invalid use of property'

I tried converting this to a function with same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA syntax requires the keyword 'set' for object reference assignments. See http://roymacleanvba.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/set-keyword/

```
    ...
    Set RecordSetCustomers = rs 
    End property
```

Comment: This was it. Unfortunately, it seems I can not do what I wanted but for reasons having nothing to with this. Thank you. It turns out that since I am using an ODBC driver with ADO (and not an OLE DB provider) there is no session provider to be passed around. Bummer. My code will not be as elegant as it would be. Wish someone would maintain an OLE DB provider for PostgreSQL... but, again, that is a separate problem. Thanks for this!

Comment: have you looked at http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/ from pgfoundry? install instructions and connection string here http://connectionstrings.com/Providers/pgoledb